# 10k user "Go get it" button for Citizen Patrol / Deputy / Marshal badges

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Many badges have "Go get it" links in the new profile pages, which I think are great because they point users to parts of the site they may not be aware of. However, the flag badges (Citizen Patrol / Deputy / Marshal) don't have any "Go get it" links:

[image]

For users with at least 10,000 reputation, I think a really natural place to link would be the moderator tools page that is unlocked at 10,000 reputation, https://stackoverflow.com/tools. Linked tools like the "New answers to old questions" list are really useful for identifying problem posts that should be flagged for moderator attention, and the "Go get it" link could be useful in increasing the visibility of these tools.

Comment: The Late Answers queue serves the same purpose and generates helpful NAA flags; it's available at 500 rep. Same with First Posts queue... but the larger issue is, do we even want to tell people "go flag stuff to raise your count"?

Comment: @HomegrownTomato good point about the Late Answers queue for 500+ users as being another option as the link target, though I thought the moderation tools page would be particularly well suited because it has a range of tools for finding problems requiring moderation. Personally I think this "Go get it" would be less problematic than, for instance, [the "Go get it" link for Sportsmanship encouraging users users to blindly upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249966/253560).